# Is this a bad design?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

```
class IStreamMetadata{
public:
    virtual DataStreamType getType() = 0;
    virtual int getMaxFieldSize()  = 0;
    virtual SourceType getSourceType() = 0;
    virtual void setType(DataStreamType dsType) = 0;
    virtual void setSourceType(SourceType )= 0;
    virtual void setMaxFieldSize(int size) = 0;
};

class IFileMetadata: public IStreamMetadata{
public: 
    virtual string getPath() = 0;
    virtual void setPath(string path) = 0;
};

class ISocketMetadata: public IStreamMetadata{
public:
    virtual int getPort() = 0;
};

class ColumnDBMetadata: public IStreamMetadata, public IFileMetadata, public ISocketMetadata
```

The `ColumnDBMetadata` is a class that is retrieve from a table database that contains information about these 3 classes(`IStreamMetadata`, `IFileMetadata`, `ISocketMetadata`.)

The compiler gives me a warning

```
C4584: 'ColumnDBMetadata' : base-class 'IStreamMetadata' is already a base-class of 'IFileMetadata'.
```

Is it better to create method inside `ColumnDBMetata` like `getStreamMetadata`, `getFileMetadata`, `getSocketMetadata`. Or maybe pass the `ColumnDBMetadata` to a factory that create the correct interface?

Comment: Look up diamond inheritance and you should find a good explanation of something missing pretty quickly.

Comment: First, make sure you ask yourself "is a" or "has a". Also, I would avoid having `class` that starts with an `I`. Makes it look like an `interface`.

Comment: if `File` is a `Stream`, what's the point of inhering both of them ?

Comment: @crashmstr: it is an interface. I forgot to implement the destructor.

Comment: This looks like Java, not C++. Lots of getters and setters, and deep inheritance. If you're not looking for polymorphism, why bother with it instead of using templates? Are the individual setters really helpful, or should they be constructor parameters instead? Or are we looking at raw data storage (in which case you should use a `struct` instead and access the elements directly instead of going through function calls)?

Comment: @DevSolar: I will look for templates.. I really dont know how to create it. U are right, they should be constructor parameters. Plz, could you post a sample code?

Comment: @Rubber: Difficult, since it would probably not be a 1:1 replacement for what you are looking at (I don't really get what your classes are intended to *achieve*). Generally speaking, if you're looking at C++ as "only" OO, you are missing out on about 75% of this language's expressiveness. (A quite common problem with coders coming from a Java background -- who create a very distinctive type of poor C++ code. ;-) )

Comment: @DevSolar: Thanks!! U are right, I am java developer too!

Comment: @Rubber: Then I hope you already got beyond the stage where you create every object with `new()` and pass lots of pointers around, frequently forgetting to `delete` them again. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to comment on semantics. As long as all classes you inherit from are pure virtual, which is C++'s way of having interfaces, this design's *shape* should be fine. However, you've made a mistake.

Your inheritance should look like this:

```
class IFileMetadata: public virtual StreamMetadata

class ISocketMetadata: public virtual IStreamMetadata

class ColumnDBMetadata: public virtual IStreamMetadata, public virtual IFileMetadata, public virtual ISocketMetadata
```

What the virtual keyword does, is fuse together all the duplicately inherited function definitions. If you don't do this, the compiler will think you're inheriting different functions of the same name, which is why you get that warning.

Basically, you should make a habit of always inheriting pure virtual 'interface' classes as

`public virtual`

---

Also, you will want to write an empty **inline virtual destructor** in all these interface classes, because the language expects one to be there even when the class doesn't do anything.

---

Mind, this design is fine because you only have pure virtual methods and nothing else. If you were to add a field or a single implemented function (aside from the destructor) in any of the inherited classes, it would be proper multiple inheritance and if you're willing to go there, you had better spend a lot of time googling the subject first.

Answer (score 4):

There is a smell...  How does a column implement a stream, a file, *and* a socket?  It seems like it may be a *consumer* of those classes, but not inherent from.

To confound matters, your base stream `interface` (I understand it's an interface from a C++ perspective rather than a real one!), does not expose enough generic functionality for it to be useful.  Your file and socket interfaces implement different semantics.  You need a more generic interface, which file/socket implement and then you just need to *pass* the base interface to the constructor of `ColumnDBMEtaData` and it can use it however it pleases because you've obfuscated the implementation.

Also consider adding this to your base interface class:

```
virtual ~IStreamMetaData() = 0 { };
```

Comment: The column just hold information about these interfaces. The columnDBMetadata is just a object to retrieve info. from database.

Comment: @Rubber, what I am saying is that it might well *use* various streams, but wouldn't inherit because it *isn't* a stream itself.  See crashmstr's comment about "is a" and "has a".

Comment: i forgot to do this, like i mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is bad design. Most people would understand this `class ColumnDBMetadata: public IStreamMetadata, public IFileMetadata, public ISocketMetadata` means that instance of `ColumnDBMetadata` is **all 3 at a same time**.

Your idea of having `getStreamMetadata, getFileMetadata, getSocketMetadata` is OK, if you want to get rid of all inheritance.

Another approach would be to reverse the hierarchy you proposed: make the DB class base interface and have socket, stream and file metadata inherit it. So you would first create the DB class (via factory), determine what is it and then downcast it to one of specialized types.

Answer (score 0):

I find classes strange that has "Data", "Info", "Manager", and the like as a suffix. All the data a stream needs (in theory) is contained (maybe even hidden) inside the class. Everytime I am tempted to make such a class I ask myself: Why do I want to do this? There must be some other way. Without knowing the context of these classes this would be an issue for me to improve the design.

Then you define many getters. I'm not saying that getters are evil in general. There are some good discussions about this topic here at SO (search for getter, setters). For me, again, getters are a hint that something could be done better. A getter says: I don't know how to do it, so here take the stuff and do it yourself. Sometimes I live with that, sometimes I find a better design for this.